# python でのandの使い方について

Tags: python

```
point=['c', 'b', 'd']
if 'a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd' in point:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

リスト内にaがないのにTrueが出力されます。andの書き方について教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `print(all(e in point for e in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`point`にa, b, c, dが全て含まれるかを評価するにはset（集合）型を使った比較を行います。
次のようなif文になります。

```
if set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) <= set(point):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

https://docs.python.jp/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset

x in y の場合 y に x が含まれるかの演算となり、質問の例の場合 `point` に 'd' が含まれるかの演算になります。
https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html#in

また演算子の優先順位が in, and の順ですので in が先に評価されます。
https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

```
if 'a' and 'b' and 'c' and ('d' in point):
-> if True and True and True and True:
```

と評価されるためTrueになっています。
'a', 'b', 'c', ('d' in point) は全てTrueと評価されます。

if ('a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd') in point: とした場合、('a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd') が先に評価され 'd' in point となり True になります。

```
>>> ('a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd')
'd'
```

Comment: if ('a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd') in point:と全体に（）をつけてもTrue出力されるのですが、これも'a', 'b', 'c', ('d' in point)と認識されているのでしょうか。

Comment: point=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']として、
if set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])  in set(point):とすると、
False出力されるのですが、setの場合inはつかえないのでしょうか。

Comment: set でも in は使えますが if set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) in set(point):の場合set(point)にset(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])が含まれるかの評価になります。point の内容が point=[set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])] であれば set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) in point はTrueです。

Comment: x in y の場合、y に含まれる要素に x はあるか？なので x は単数です。xがリストやセットなどの場合はそのリストやセット自体が含まれるかの評価になります。

Answer (score 3):

pythonの`and`演算子は左辺が`bool(左辺)`でTrueと評価されるとき右辺の値を、Falseのとき左辺の値を返します。

たとえば、`'a'`はTrueと評価されるため、`'a' and 'b'`は`'b'`となります。
`''`はFalseと評価されるため、`'' and 'b'`は`''`となります。

質問の例ですと、

```py
 'a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd' in point
 -> 'a' and 'b' and 'c' and True
 -> 'b' and 'c' and True
 -> 'c' and True
 -> True
```

Comment: 結果は同じになるのですが、`and`演算子では[短絡評価(short circuit)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)が行われるため左から簡約すべきですね。`True and 'b' and 'c' and 'd' in point`->`True and 'c' and 'd' in point`->...